# How to infer generic type of a generic

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an interface called **Expression** that through an **OperatorExpression** goes back to itself in like an infinite nesting structure.

Im passing in a generic that already has a generic and I would like to infer it.

I have the following interfaces:

```
type Expression<T, U = string> = (T extends Approval<U> ? Approval<U> : Condition<U>) | OperatorExpression<T, U>

interface OperatorExpression<U, T = string> {
   operands: Expression<T, U>[]
   // other stuff
}

interface Approval<T = string> {
   approver: T
   // other stuff
}

interface Condition<T = string> {
   id: T
   // other stuff
}
```

And then when I use the Expression with a generic that has a generic that is not string, I have to call it like this:

```
Expression<Approval<Types.ObjectId>, Types.ObjectId>
```

And I would like to be able to call it like this: `Expression<Approval<Types.ObjectId>>`, basically infer the second generic based on the generic of the first generic.

In my little ts knowledge I imagined to do something like this, but it complains because "S" does not exist:

```
type Expression<T extends (Approval<S> | Condition<S>), U = S> = (T extends Approval<U> ? Approval<U> : Condition<U>) | OperatorExpression<T, U>
```

How could I do this? Thank you

---

edit

Since this is now solved thanks @Meowster, I'll put down here his solution integrated in my use case

```
type InferType<T> = T extends Approval<infer E> | WorkflowCondition<infer E> ? E : never;

type R<T> = InferType<T>

 export type Expression<T, U = R<T>> =
    | (T extends Approval<U> ? Approval<U> : T extends WorkflowCondition<U> ? WorkflowCondition<U> : WorkflowApproval<U>)
    | OperatorExpression<T, U>
```

Comment: What is `S` supposed to do? You have to declare it as a (optional) type parameter if you're going to use it in the type declaration.

Comment: S is basically the Types.ObjectId that I pass in, I dont want to write two times Types.ObjectId like this `Expression<Approval<Types.ObjectId>, Types.ObjectId>`, but instead do just `Expression<Approval<Types.ObjectId>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
type Expression<T extends Approval | Condition> = T | OperatorExpression<T>

interface OperatorExpression<T extends Approval | Condition> {
   operands: Expression<T>[]
   // other stuff
}

interface Approval<U = any> {
   approver: U
   // other stuff
}

interface Condition<U = any> {
   id: U
   // other stuff
}

type E = OperatorExpression<Approval<number>>
type O = E['operands'] // Expression<Approval<number>>[]
```

or use infer syntax

```js
type InferType<T> = T extends Approval<infer E> | Condition<infer E> ? E : never;

interface Approval<T = string> {
    approver: T
    // other stuff
 }
 
 interface Condition<T = string> {
    id: T
    // other stuff
 }

 type R = InferType<Approval<number>> // R = number
```